# Attribute error 'QueryDict' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: django

I'm trying to send a post request from PostMan into my Django view and I'm getting this error. "AttributeError: 'QueryDict' object has no attribute '_meta'"
From what I've gathered it has something to do with the form.save() as seen in traceba
I've searched all over to find a solution or even a better way to achieve an image post from a external web client to a Django server. 
All help is very much appreciated.

**Traceback**

```
Capture.PNG
form is valid
Internal Server Error: /getimg/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gedit\Desktop\django\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Gedit\Desktop\django\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Gedit\Desktop\django\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Gedit\Desktop\django\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Gedit\Desktop\django\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Gedit\Desktop\django\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Gedit\Desktop\django\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Gedit\Desktop\django\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\Gedit\Desktop\django\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Gedit\Desktop\django\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Gedit\Desktop\django\indivproj\getimg\api\views.py", line 21, in getimg
    form.save()
  File "C:\Users\Gedit\Desktop\django\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 207, in save
    self.instance = self.update(self.instance, validated_data)
  File "C:\Users\Gedit\Desktop\django\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 979, in update
    info = model_meta.get_field_info(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Gedit\Desktop\django\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\utils\model_meta.py", line 35, in get_field_info
    opts = model._meta.concrete_model._meta
AttributeError: 'QueryDict' object has no attribute '_meta'
[24/Mar/2020 13:39:25] "POST /getimg/ HTTP/1.1" 500 20251
```

**Views.py**

```
@api_view(['POST',])
def getimg(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageSerializer(request.POST, request.FILES)
        logger.warning(request.FILES['img'])
        if form.is_valid():
            #raise_exception=True
            logger.warning('form is valid')
            form.save()
            logger.warning()
            response_dict = {'post': 'success'}
            return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_dict), content_type='application/javascript')
        else:
            logger.warning(form.errors)
    else:
        form = ImageSerializer()
    return render(request, 'getimg.html', {'form': form})
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = '__all__'
```

**Models.py**

```
class Image(models.Model):
   # name = models.CharField(default='name', max_length=30)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', max_length=1000)
```

**Urls.py**

```
app_name = 'getimg'
urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /polls/
    path('', views.getimg, name='getimg'),

    path('gettext/', views.gettext, name='gettext'),
    path('success', views.success, name = 'success'),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**Postman**
[image: The postman post request]

Answer (score 0):

so after looking around as a smart individual I realized i have not defined what save() function is... so now i do

**The code that fixed the error but still not working**

```
    def save(self):
    img = Image(
               img =self.validated_data['img'],
        )
```